# .remove() is not working when checkbox's unchecked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I am having a little problem where I am trying to check and uncheck the checkbox. When I checked it, it show the following picture:
[image: here]

It should appears the buttons, delete, rename and share, appended to the upload and new folder. But I can't remove the append after is unchecked.

My code is the following: (jQuery)

```
var ids = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;
for(i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {               
                var sel = $("input[id='" + ids[i] + "']");
                $(sel).on('click', function(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    $.each(sel, function( sel ) {
                        if($(sel).is(':checked')) {
                            $("#del").remove();
                            $("#rename").remove();
                            $("#sharing").remove();
                            $(sel).prop('checked', false );
                        } else {
                            $(sel).prop('checked', true );
                            $("#del").remove();
                            $("#rename").remove();
                            $("#sharing").remove();
                            $(".sub-menu-files ul").append("<li class=\"delbtn\"><button id=\"del\">Delete File</button</li> <li class=\"renamebtn\"><button id=\"rename\">Rename</button></li> <li class=\"sharingbtn\"><button id=\"sharing\">Sharing</button></li>");
                            $("#del").click(function() {
                                var sels = $("tbody tr input");

                                $(sels).each(function() {
                                    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                                        alert($(this).attr('id') + " has been deleted");
                                        $.post("delete.php", {id: $(this).attr('id') }, function(data) {
                                            if(data != "") {
                                                alert("Your file/files have been sent to the Trash. To delete them from our server, go to \"Deleted Files\" and delete it.");
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });


            }
```

The `ids` is going to pick to the database the id of the uploaded file. I tried everything, but no good.

My php + HTML content is:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="select" class="case" id="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" style="cursor: pointer;" /></td>
```

Is also picking the id.

Is there anyway I can make it work?

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because while the script is running for the first time those elements does not exists yet.

Therefore, you should refer them through an element that is exists the all time, body is good.

```
$('body').find('#del').remove();
```

This should work

Comment: It is not working... When I uncheck it back it stays there and doesn't remove.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.  You don't even need the embedded PHP section. It's really two handlers.

```js
//handler for #del.  you only need to declare this once, as a global.
$(document).on("click", "#del", function() {
  var sels = $("tbody tr input:checked");

  $(sels).each(function() {

    alert($(this).attr('id') + " has been deleted");
    $.post("delete.php", {
      id: $(this).attr('id')
    }, function(data) {
      if (data != "") {
        alert("Your file/files have been sent to the Trash." +
          " To delete them from our server, go to \"Deleted Files\" and delete it.");
      }
    });

  });
});

//handler for check boxes
$(document).on("change", "tbody tr input", function(e) {
  //See if any are checked.
  if ($("tbody tr input:checked").length > 0) {
    {
      $(".sub-menu-files ul").append("<li class=\"delbtn\"><button id=\"del\">Delete File" +
        "</button</li> <li class=\"renamebtn\"><button id=\"rename\">" +
        "Rename</button></li> <li class=\"sharingbtn\">" + " <
        button id = \"sharing\">Sharing</button></li>");
    } else {
      $("#del, #rename, #sharing").remove();
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. It was just change the `$(sel).on('click', function() {` function to inside of the `$.each(sel, function(sel) {` function and convert the ***`sel`*** from ***`on('click')`*** to ***`this`***.

Everyone who tried to help me I want to appreciate it.